# Accessibility. How to inform the user that a KendoGrid has an input box

Tags: kendo-ui, accessibility

In this demo

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing

How will an NVDA user know that the grid contains textbox's that you can enter when navigating via the tab keys?